# io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: DefaultFullHttpRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, illegalstateexception, encoder

I am getting this exception intermediately while hitting the API in bulk. What is the reason that I am facing this issue?

`io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: DefaultFullHttpRequest, state: 1\tat io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:104)\tSuppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: Error has been observed at the following site(s):\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\t`

Comment: Will you be able to identify the cause and solution? I am facing a similar issue.